# How to get access to underlying POJO from GWT Editor class

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I have a HashMap inside my POJO that I am using the Editor framework in GWT to edit.  While I have access to the standard member variables bound through thier getters/setters, I don't know how to access the values inside the HashMap.  How do I get access to the underlying POJO that is being edited through my editor that is using the SimpleBeanEditorDriver?

My POJO:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored=true)
public class ProfileConfig extends BaseEntity {
     @Indexed(unique=true)
     private String name;
     private boolean isDefault;
     private HashMap<ProfileID, ProfileInfo> profiles= new HashMap<ProfileID, ProfileInfo>();

     public ProfileInfo getProfile(ProfileID id) {
          return profiles.get(id);
     }

     public void setProfile(ProfileID id, ProfileInfo p) {
         profiles.put(id, p);
     }
```

My Editor:

```
public class ProfileConfigEditor extends Composite implements ManagedObjectEditor<ProfileConfig> {

     private static ProfileConfigEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ProfileConfigEditorUiBinder.class);
     interface ProfileConfigEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ProfileConfigEditor> {
}

     private UserManager userManager;

     @UiField
     CellList Profiles;
     @UiField
     TextBox name;
     @UiField
     CheckBox isDefault;
```

So given that I have a list of valid Profile ids from the userManager, how do I go about calling the getProfile method from my POJO from within my Editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `ValueAwareEditor`.

```
public class ProfileConfigEditor extends Composite implements ManagedObjectEditor<ProfileConfig>, ValueAwareEditor<ProfileConfig> {

void setValue(ProfileConfig value){
    // TODO: Call ProfileConfig.getProfile()
}

void flush(){
   // TODO: Call ProfileConfig.setProfile()
}


// ... Other methods here
```

**Alternatively**, if you want more of a challenge, you can look at rolling your own `CompositeEditor`, for example see the source code for `ListEditor`. In your case, you would implement a `CompositeEditor<ProfileConfig, ProfileInfo, MyNewProfileInfoEditor>`. You can this of this as "This editor will take a `ProfileConfig` object, extract one or more `ProfileInfo` objects and edit it with one or more `MyNewProfileInfoEditor` editors"